# how can i import my database specifying user on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am **very** new on ruby (and rails) and I just want to import a project (already on progress), and I set the rails server and all, but I realized the databases.yml is not with it, there is a **databases-remote.yml** that says `adapter: mysql2` which makes me think they are using mysql and I created a user and password and then in my part of migrates I found many files .rb that are defining a class that represents (I think) a table, with a date format in the beggin, so... reading I found out that I can import with `rake db:migrate` but it generates me an error authenticating the root user, I defined on my databases.yml the user of mysql with the password, is anyway to specify it also when I make the `rake db:migrate` ??

Thanks

Comment: quick note: it should be named `database.yml`.  Might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rake db:migrate` connects to the database you specify in `config/database.yml`, in the `development` section and creates the necessary structure so you can run the project. I think that the problem is that you need to copy `config/database-remote.yml` to `config/database.yml` and specify the user/password there.

Also, try connecting manually to MySQL with the user you created so you can test that the connection works:

```
> mysql -u your_username -p -D your_database
> Enter password: *****
```

Comment: It's a bit odd that he's getting an authentication error instead of a no such file error for database.yml.  Might mean there's more to this problem than meets the eye.  Like, what is config/database-remote.yml there for in the first place?

Comment: @numbers1311407 right, but maybe there's a database.yml file with another user/password.

Comment: it worked! thank you, it imported the databases, but when I try to reach the app I get Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) .. any idea??? (I saw in the schema the tables were created)

Comment: @jpganz18 mmm, can you paste the error stack trace? Maybe on a new question.

Answer (score 0):

@jpganz18, there may be a password for your database but there can be no password provided in database.yml file. check it or if you are confused then paste error msg here

Comment: thank you.. well, I actually did it, pasted the field password = mypassword there and it worked